# (Google Maps API - reverse geocode) Getting null on cities data (Brazilians cities , for instance)

Tags: java, android, geocode

Lately, i am having problems with a code i have been using some years ago. It is an Android java code to get the city, state and country using google Maps API(reverse geocode). After sending the latitude, longitude the Google server must return the City. But the server is returning null.  I am posting the code and the printscreen of the issue. It is happening with Brazilians cities.
Some countries does not have this problem.

Attempt_A [City:São Paulo(Population:12 million) / State:São Paulo / Country:Brazil]
Result: Returned null on the CITY field
[Latitude,Longitude]: [-23.590630, -46.660867]

Attempt_B [City: Rio de Janeiro(Population: 6.5 million) / State:Rio de Janeiro / Country:Brazil ]
Result: Returned null on the CITY field
[Latitude,Longitude]: [-22.972394, -43.185209]

The code below is not working for most of brazilian cities i have tried to parse. 
city = addresses.get(0).getLocality(); // GET CITY

The city field keeps resulting null in all my attempts on brazilians cities, PS1:I did not get the problem in USA cities and Europe cities. PS2: The address field, country, state and everything else is working fine

I have already made some attempts(changes API key, change API version, Locale.ENGLISH definition, test on emulator and real devices,) however the issue remains.

```
//send latitude and longitude data to Google and get City,state and Country data
public void gcode(){

    Log.e(TAG_DEBUG, " gcode function ");

    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses;
    geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.ENGLISH);

    try {

        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latToParse, longitToParse, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5

        city = addresses.get(0).getLocality(); // GET CITY
        state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea(); // GET STATE
        country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName(); // GET COUNTRY
        String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
        String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName(); // Only if available else return NULL
        Log.e(TAG_DEBUG, "Country,State,City: " + country +" "+  state +" "+ city);

        String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); //GET Address

        Log.e(TAG_DEBUG, "postalCode: " + postalCode);
        Log.e(TAG_DEBUG, "knownName: " + knownName);
        Log.e(TAG_DEBUG, "address: " + address);


        if(country!=null){
            countryStr=country;

            countryStr=countryStr.toUpperCase();
            Log.e(TAG_DEBUG, "CountryStr: "+countryStr);

        }else{
            countryStr="null";
        }


        if(state!=null){
            stateStr=state;
            stateStr=stateStr.toUpperCase();
            Log.e(TAG_DEBUG, "StateStr: "+stateStr);

        }else{
            stateStr="null";
        }


        if(city!=null){

            cityStr=city;
            cityStr=cityStr.toUpperCase();
            Log.e(TAG_DEBUG, "CityStr: "+cityStr);

        }else{
            cityStr="null";
            Log.e(TAG_DEBUG, "CityStr: "+cityStr);
        }






        geocoderOk=true;
        geocoderIntStr="1";
        Log.e(TAG_DEBUG, " geocoderOk: " +geocoderOk);


        //Display city,state,country data on editTexts
        displayCityStateCountry();




    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG_DEBUG, "IO" + e);
        geocoderOk=false;
        geocoderIntStr="2";
        Log.e(TAG_DEBUG, " geocoderOk: " +geocoderOk);


        etCity.setText("Geocoder did not worked!");

    }





}

//Display city,state,country data on editTexts
public void displayCityStateCountry(){

    etCity.setText(cityStr);
    etState.setText(stateStr);
    etCountry.setText(countryStr);

}
```

In the code the country, state and city should be displayed. But the city field is displaying null. If you try to get the address it will be fine also. The problem is occuring just with the city data on brazilians cities.

Comment: Have you managed to solve it? have the same issue